# Search an array in typescript and type the match

Tags: typescript

The return type of Array.find is a list of all possible matches. I am wondering if I can narrow it down.

Consider the following situation:

```js
type MyArray = [{type: 'big', some: true}, { type: 'small', other: false}];

const findInArr = <T extends MyArray, Q extends MyArray[number], R extends Q['type']>(arr: T, type: R) => {
    return arr.find((i) => i.type === type)
}

const result = findInArr(theArray, 'big'); // Should have the type {type: 'big', some: true}
```

I have been playing around the whole day but can't figure this one out.

I have succeeded by type casting and by using type guards, however I am wondering if there is a more safe and elegant way.

Anything that points me in the correct direction is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Where is type `Arr` defined? How can `Q` be inferred?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXgV8W) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing (and consider [edit]ing the question to clarify anything it misses; I'm wondering when you say "using type guards" if you've already considered this approach, but since "using type guards" encompasses all of narrowing, I can't be sure)?

Comment: @Dai Ah, I renamed my type and forgot to update the function definition. I fixed it now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an explicit return type that is created from your generic types.

That looks like it might be this:

```
Extract<T[number], { type: R }> | undefined
```

`Extract` returns only the types from a union (first parameter) that match a type (second parameter). So this resolves to only the array members that have the `type` property that was passed in.

---

So that looks like this:

```
const findInArr = <
    T extends Arr,
    R extends T[number]['type']
>(
    arr: T,
    type: R
): Extract<T[number], { type: R }> | undefined => {
    return arr.find((i) => i.type === type) 
}
```

(Note that I removed `Q`, as it's a useless generic type that is trivially derived from what is already there)

And it seems to work when used:

```
declare const theArray: MyArray

const result = findInArr(theArray, 'big'); // {type: 'big', some: true}
if (result) result.some // fine
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnKBeKBvKpIC4oGdhwCWAdgOZQC+A2gLoBQm0AsiPHAIYjJRWqM4ByAEaFSAgDR4A9gFsIOAgFcIFSen5QBuGewA2uiVCnAAFhDg4AZntwqaAbjp0AxlOL4olkgBMAksTZuAB46KDCoABUoCAAPYAhib1xYBHFQ8IAlaLiEpMiqYkUZIXMaKgFGAXoAPgAKdLD2BBwItPCMcHkoDLoAShwAUTiOZ2AgiIKikrgaNQ7sbspqqAAfKEVEiC9iCG9kZdQGqDgIYEU4YigmuAA6be9a2sJe-ahCG8ZkJBRGF7oKJzeCDOXRNaCudzADBmNicHAsWEgJwQjwnXCKXRQlD3fxsWqmCCIyTCUQCXr2KAAekpaA0JLEklwsi6ShUdEIligtTRGOALx5mJuTLkVJp2wgdCAA)

---

But there's one type error still, inside this function on the `return`.

```
Type '{ type: string; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Extract<T[number], { type: R; }> | undefined'.
  Type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Extract<T[number], { type: R; }>'.(2322)
```

The built in `find` method on arrays is typed to return a union type of all array members. But you can use a type predicate function passed to `find` that tells TypeScript what returning `true` means for the resulting type.

So you can add `i is Extract<T[number], { type: R }>` to the return type of the find callback and everything works.

```
const findInArr = <
    T extends Arr,
    R extends T[number]['type']
>(
    arr: T,
    type: R
): Extract<T[number], { type: R }> | undefined => {
    return arr.find(
        (i): i is Extract<T[number], { type: R }> => {
            return i.type === type
        }
    )
}
```

[See Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnKBeKBvKpIC4oGdhwCWAdgOZQC+A2gLoBQm0AsiPHAIYjJRWqM4ByAEaFSAgDR4A9gFsIOAgFcIFSen5QBuGewA2uiVCnAAFhDg4AZntwqaAbjp0AxlOL4olkgBMAksTZuAB46KDCoABUoCAAPYAhib1xYBHFQ8IAlaLiEpMiqYkUZIXMaKgFGAXoAPgAKdLD2BBwItPCMcHkoDLoAShwAUTiOZ2AgiIKikrgaNQ7sbspqqAAfKEVEiC9iCG9kZdQGqDgIYEU4YigmuAA6be9a2sJe-ahCG8ZkJBRGF-ZcI7tIYEdijcaTYqlOYaLIUZZrDbeLYkXZ0ChOJHOXRNaCudzADBmNicHAsYkgJx4jwnXCKXQElD3fxsWqmCDkyTCUQCXr2KAAen5aA0XLEklwsi6ShUdEIligtRpdOALyV9JuErkAqF2wgdCAA)

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

The resulting type is what you expect without `undefined`, since each item is guaranteed to be present.

`Extract` picks whichever type extends `{ type: ArrItemType }` from the union, allowing the whole thing to work.

```
type MyArray = [{ type: 'big', some: true }, { type: 'small', other: false }];

const findInArr = <
  TArr extends MyArray,
  ArrItem extends TArr[number],
  ArrItemType extends ArrItem['type']
>(arr: TArr, type: ArrItemType): Extract<ArrItem, { type: ArrItemType }> => {
  return arr.find((i) => i.type === type) as Extract<ArrItem, { type: ArrItemType }>;
}

const result = findInArr(
  [{ type: 'big', some: true }, { type: 'small', other: false }],
  'small'
); // Should have the type {type: 'big', some: true}
```